# Inverting vector basis and how it affects vectors defined in standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We consider here a vector basis  $B_R$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$  that is derived from the standard basis

$$
E=\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) ,\;\left( \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right) \right\} 
$$

$B_R$ being rotated by 90° in counter clock wise direction gives the new vector basis:

$$
B_R=\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right) ,\;\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -1\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) \right\} 
$$

So, from my understanding, this new vector basis $B_R$ should transform every vector in standard basis $E$ to new basis $B_R$.

From this matrix we can easily derive its inverse by transposing it:
$$
R=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  -1\\
 1&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) ,R^{-1}=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  1\\
 -1&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$$

**Question**: In terms of vector basis change the matrix $R$  transforms a vectors coordinates from basis $B_R$ to basis $E$, which is opposite to my understanding as I see that it should transforms a vectors coordinates from basis $E$ to basis $B_R$. Can you please show me what is wrong with my reasoning?

[image]
([Source](http://www.michaelkeutel.de/) image)

Comment: I didn't get your reasoning since you only wrote '*from my understanding*' which indeed seems to be incorrect. Try to convince yourself (prove) the correct statement in the beginning of your 'Question' paragraph.

Comment: @Berci. Thank you. I am trying to understand the intuition behind the concept rather than prove it in.

Comment: Well, as you observed, it can indeed be a bit contraintuitive..